# What nutrition do flies find in feces?

Tags: entomology, nutrition

How are flies able to extract nutrition in feces when the originating animal wasn't able to? What makes flies more capable?

Comment: I wonder how much (by percentage) of feces consists of bacteria. These would be added nutrients, wouldn't they? Also, feces are not entirely digested, so even if bacteria provided nothing extra, there would still be nutrition for the taking, with the right enzymes.

Comment: Someone's trash is another's treasure.

Comment: Bacteria comprise about 50% of the fecal mass. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7359576